# Protobuf 3.0.0-alpha1 install on windows. Virus?

Tags: windows, installation, antivirus, virus, protobuf-c

I was just trying to install protobuf 3.0.0-alpha1 on windows using MSYS and MinGW, and it fails at checking if my C compiler works. Just as it fails each time, my Norton auto-block window comes up and says that it blocked a.exe because it contains SAPE.heur.3161 virus.

Anyone know what to do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning your antivirus off. It sounds like it is improperly detecting a test program compiled by the configure script (which is done to check if the compiler works) as a virus and deleting the resulting executable. This is leading the configure script to conclude that your compiler doesn't work.

Comment: This was the case. I fixed it a while back and forgot to answer myself. But thank you!